# Order by count of related model in django?

Tags: django

I'm trying to order a queryset by the count of another model that queryset relates to.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...

class PostView(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="post_views")
```

Now, I would assume that this would work:

```
Post.objects.all().order_by('post_views')
```

But I get this error:

> AttributeError at /api/posts/?order_by=views
>
> 'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'attname'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to order by the number of related `PostView` instances, you should annotate the queryset with the count, then order by the annotated field.

```
from django.db.models import Count

Post.objects.annotate(num_views=Count('post_views')).order_by('num_views')
```

Comment: I can't remember off the top of my head whether it's `Count('post_views')` or `Count('postview')`.